# PHP 5 Upgrade On Ubuntu Not Working With Magento

Tags: php, magento, ubuntu

I had an outdated version of PHP on my system, so attempted to upgrade from `5.5.9` to `5.6`.

I followed the following steps on my Digital Ocean Ubuntu droplet:

I installed Ondřej Surý's PPA and selected `5.6` as well as other packages related to the main one, like the XML package.

When I do `php -v` on my server, it says

```
PHP 5.6.29-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

This indicated to me that the update went through.

But when I restart my apache server and check the error logs, it says

`Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 configured -- resuming normal operations`

I believe the latest version of Magento on my server is giving me this error (`HTTP 500`) because it is using the wrong version of PHP...

How do I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The digital ocean community site [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-upgrade-from-php-v-5-5-9-to-v-5-6) offered a couple of extra commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6 php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mysql php5.6-xml
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo a2enmod php5.6
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Note the a2dismod and a2enmod steps. The post says:

> Without the a2dismod/a2ensmod steps, Apache will continue to see your older version of PHP, even if command line is seeing the new version.